# Is there any onNavigateUp-android-like method in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In my case, I want to clear or reset my data in Notifier whenever the specific page getting popped (destroyed?). I had tried many ways but nothing worked so far..

I also tried to clear the data first in build method, like this:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  
  notifier.clearData()

  ...
  ...
}
```

However, flutter doesn't allow this operation while a widget is getting constructed. So I think of thing like onNavigateUp method in android would work, but didn't find any. Could anyone suggest how to achieve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with widget lifecycle observer? maybe these methods can help

didPopRoute() → Future
Called when the system tells the app to pop the current route. For example, on Android, this is called when the user presses the back button.

didPushRoute(String route) → Future
Called when the host tells the application to push a new route onto the navigator.

didPushRouteInformation(RouteInformation routeInformation) → Future
Called when the host tells the application to push a new RouteInformation and a restoration state onto the router.

[follow this doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html)

Comment: Thanks, mate.. I didn't know that those methods exist. This is what exactly I was looking for.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome, can you upvote my answer?

Comment: Sure, mate.. But I can't already upvote any as my reputation.